# currentThread() is always the currentThread()?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java `Thread`, 
the method `currentThread()`
returns the memory reference of the "currently executing thread". 
"Currently executing thread" here is the thread that invoked this `currentThread()`.

I'm wondering whether there is an exceptional case to this, i.e. 
whether `currentThread()` returns some other thread than the one invoked it.

Eg.: suppose, in the `main` method, i'm invoking `Thread.currentThread().toString()` to see it-- and it returns the `toString()` representation of the `main` thread.

The Q is, can there be a case that it returns some other thread that is running in memory?

I can't think of one. `currentThread()` here is executing on `main` thread-- thus whenever it is up & running, it is the main thread space it is executing on. 
I don't see how else it could be unless there are some slips.

`currentThread()` is native-- can' see these in the code.

Comment: It would be fairly useless if it did...

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why this question has come up. The docs for the method say it returns the currently executing thread, which you seem to understand, but you then ask if that's what it does. Is there a reason you're wondering if the method behaves as the docs say it should?

Comment: I find the naming of the method and the javadoc typically obtuse. In a multi-threading environment, there can be multiple concurrently executing "current" threads. If it really does what it says it does, it should return an array of threads. It should have been named "thisThread".

Comment: *currentThread* is extremely semantically clear and specific. It is the **current thread** that is making the call. That can only be one thread, the **current** one.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm wondering whether there is an exceptional case to this, i.e. whether `currentThread()` returns some other thread than the one invoked it.

No. There is no such case.

Answer (score 1):

`can there be a case that it returns some other thread that is running in memory`

```
Thread.currentThread()-
```

Always Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object and there is no exception to this.

Answer (score -1):

> Eg.: suppose, in the main method, i'm invoking
>   Thread.currentThread().toString() to see it-- and it returns the
>   toString() representation of the main thread.
>
> The Q is, can there be a case that it returns some other thread that
>   is running in memory?

It could if another thread calls main().  Never tried it, but I don't see why it should not be possible.

Comment: in that case - shouldn't the other thread calling main would be another thread, calling `currentThread()` in that thread's local space? 

the `main()` method here is static, running on an instance of class `Class`.  

i rather was concerned about the interference between threads. something like: one thread calls `currentThread()`, while `currentThread()` is up'n running, 
another thread taking over the CPU time is stored with its id etc wherever `currentThread()` is eventually looking up. but this would be poor design.

Comment: So you're asking if `Thread.currentThread()` is thread-safe? Although the documentation does not explicitely say so (!), we can assume it is thread-safe, indeed. Otherwise it would possibly not do what the documentation says - return the current thread.

Comment: "It could if another thread calls main()."...  Yeah, it would return a different Thread than the main() thread in that case but it _still_ would be returning the Thread that called it.  I agree with @yshavit here:  Why are we discussing whether or not a _standard_ library routine does what its documentation _says_ it does?  If there is some implementation where it doesn't do what the doc says, then it's the implementation that's wrong.  Not the documentation.

Comment: I only added this answer to emphasize that threads don't need code of their own, only execution context/stack.  Sure, syscalls and lib calls in a multithreaded environment MUST work correctly, else chaos will reign over the land of nasal demons.

Comment: this *answer* just adds to the OP confusion in my opinion.**currentThread** means the same thing regardless of the `method` that calls it. It is always the **currentThread**. If they are conflating that with the *main* or *initial* thread, this just adds confidence to their conflation, instead of clearly stating that **no it will never happen**.